# How do I capture the time at which an entry was added to the database?

Tags: php, sql-server, timestamp

using MSSQL 2008 and PHP, is it possible to capture the time at which a record was added to the database?

I thought the built in 'Timestamp' data type did this, but I'm getting some really weird hex like thing...

0x00000000000007D3

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `datetime` column with a default value `getdate()`.

```
create table YourTable
(
  Created datetime default getdate()
)
```